# How can I move ld.so higher in virtual memory?

Tags: linux, memory, shared-libraries, elf, mmap

My tool needs to recreate a portion of the memory layout of another processes.  To do this reliably, I created a stub/wrapper that turns off ASLR, links only against `libdl` and `libc` to minimize the space taken up, then `mmap()`s the required address range using `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE`.

Once that succeeds, the wrapper `dlopen()`s the rest of the code that does what it needs to with the memory.

Lately, the memory layouts this tool has encountered has begun to include bits that infringe into the memory used by `libdl` and `libc` in the wrapper, causing the `mmap()` to fail.

The memory map of the wrapper looks like this at the time of `mmap()`:

```
00401000-00402000 r-xp 00001000 08:11 52960164                           /wrapper
00402000-00403000 r--p 00002000 08:11 52960164                           /wrapper
00403000-00404000 r--p 00002000 08:11 52960164                           /wrapper
00404000-00405000 rw-p 00003000 08:11 52960164                           /wrapper
7ffff7db0000-7ffff7db3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7db3000-7ffff7dd5000 r--p 00000000 08:02 786706                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
7ffff7dd5000-7ffff7f4d000 r-xp 00022000 08:02 786706                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
7ffff7f4d000-7ffff7f9b000 r--p 0019a000 08:02 786706                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
7ffff7f9b000-7ffff7f9f000 r--p 001e7000 08:02 786706                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
7ffff7f9f000-7ffff7fa1000 rw-p 001eb000 08:02 786706                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
7ffff7fa1000-7ffff7fa5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7fa5000-7ffff7fa6000 r--p 00000000 08:02 786744                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.31.so
7ffff7fa6000-7ffff7fa8000 r-xp 00001000 08:02 786744                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.31.so
7ffff7fa8000-7ffff7fa9000 r--p 00003000 08:02 786744                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.31.so
7ffff7fa9000-7ffff7faa000 r--p 00003000 08:02 786744                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.31.so
7ffff7faa000-7ffff7fab000 rw-p 00004000 08:02 786744                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.31.so
7ffff7fab000-7ffff7fad000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7fc9000-7ffff7fcd000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffff7fcd000-7ffff7fcf000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffff7fcf000-7ffff7fd0000 r--p 00000000 08:02 786696                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
7ffff7fd0000-7ffff7ff3000 r-xp 00001000 08:02 786696                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
7ffff7ff3000-7ffff7ffb000 r--p 00024000 08:02 786696                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
7ffff7ffc000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 0002c000 08:02 786696                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7ffe000 rw-p 0002d000 08:02 786696                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
7ffff7ffe000-7ffff7fff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 --xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Looking at the layout, it seems that it reserves a lot of room for the stack to grow downward with the highest address used by `ld.so` being the limit of stack growth.

Now, I happen to know that my tool does not need a lot of stack space, so I was wondering: Is there any way to move ld.so higher, presumably allowing the other dlls to be loaded higher, such that there is little or no chance of overlapping with the memory regions I need to reserve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I happen to know that my tool does not need a lot of stack space,

Try setting `ulimit -s 128` before running the tool. That should reduce the amount of space reserved for stack.

> so I was wondering: Is there any way to move ld.so higher

Not really: `ld.so` is `mmap`ed by the kernel at randomized address.

In general, if you want to control where in memory your binary runs, you should make a stand-alone self-relocating executable, which you can then relocate anywhere you want. See e.g. [rtldi](http://www.bitwagon.com/rtldi/rtldi.html) and/or [UPX](https://upx.github.io/) for inspiration.

Comment: I turn off ASLR for this process, so it's not randomized.  Is there any way to change the fixed address it is loaded at?

Comment: @Grisby_2133 Sure: you can build a special kernel that will load this particular binary somewhere else. Short of doing that, I don't believe there is.

Comment: Thanks.  Occasionally when you try to do the impossible, it turns out it's actually impossible.  If you update your answer to reflect this, I'll accept it.